# Mysql select statement only works on first iteration in while loop, insert working fine

Tags: mysql

Why is the `SELECT` statement inside the WHILE loop only returning value for the first iteration ?
Both of the `INSERT IGNORE` and the second `INSERT` is working, and are inserting rows equal to `amount`.
If I set `amount` to 10, I only get the results from the first inserted row. However, the procedure will `INSERT` `amount` rows to `rand_strings` and `rand_strings_info` tables.

The Procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE if exists test_while;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_while(amount INT, description VARCHAR(255)) 
BEGIN
WHILE amount > 0 DO
  INSERT IGNORE INTO rand_strings(rand_string) /*WORKS EVERY ITERATION*/
  SELECT generate_rand_string();       /*function to generate a random string.*/

  SELECT * FROM rand_strings WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); /*ONLY WORKS FIRST TIME */

  INSERT INTO rand_strings_info(id, col2, col3) /*WORKS EVERY ITERATION*/
  VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), now(), description);

  SET amount = amount - 1;

END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;


CALL test_while(10, 'This is the description of the string…')

RESULTS:

id | rand_string

1  | jgdlkjaht
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some interfaces do not show all the results as expected, but the code runs correctly.

You can see in the following <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/801b8/1)</kbd> that only shows the first record in the `rand_strings` table when stored procedure runs, but running the same code on the MySQL command line the result is as follows:

```sql
mysql> CALL `test_while`(5, 'This is the description of the string...');
+----+------------------------------------------+
| id | rand_string                              |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | f4c77a3155d95ad1e818b1b06a62deec8e0b6754 |
+----+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------------------------------------------+
| id | rand_string                              |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 7cbcca49596262836f5af91643303d10b3804900 |
+----+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------------------------------------------+
| id | rand_string                              |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  3 | 2ba2c7276c0b66e3dcbb971b7f54af9bced578a4 |
+----+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------------------------------------------+
| id | rand_string                              |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  4 | d52426b19a59c515b02268347c508383873d4d73 |
+----+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----+------------------------------------------+
| id | rand_string                              |
+----+------------------------------------------+
|  5 | fbc25c6204b609e8f4f4f8a33b534bff9a011e5f |
+----+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test_while`(`amount` INT, `description` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  DECLARE `_LAST_INSERT_ID`, `_first_inserted_in_this_run` INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_generate_rand_string` (
    `insert_id` INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    `first_inserted_in_this_run` INT UNSIGNED
  ) ENGINE=MEMORY;

  WHILE `amount` > 0 DO
    INSERT IGNORE INTO `rand_strings`(`rand_string`) /*WORKS EVERY ITERATION*/
    SELECT `generate_rand_string`(); /*function to generate a random string.*/
    SET `_LAST_INSERT_ID` := LAST_INSERT_ID();

    IF (`_first_inserted_in_this_run` IS NULL) THEN
      SET `_first_inserted_in_this_run` := `_LAST_INSERT_ID`;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO `temp_generate_rand_string` (`insert_id`, `first_inserted_in_this_run`)
    VALUES
    (`_LAST_INSERT_ID`, `_first_inserted_in_this_run`);

    -- SELECT * FROM `rand_strings` WHERE `id` = `_LAST_INSERT_ID`; /*ONLY WORKS FIRST TIME */

    INSERT INTO `rand_strings_info`(`id`, `col2`, `col3`) /*WORKS EVERY ITERATION*/
    VALUES (`_LAST_INSERT_ID`, NOW(), `description`);

    SET `amount` := `amount` - 1;
  END WHILE;

  SELECT `rs`.`id`, `rs`.`rand_string`
  FROM `rand_strings` `rs`
    INNER JOIN `temp_generate_rand_string` `tgrs` ON
     `tgrs`.`first_inserted_in_this_run` = `_first_inserted_in_this_run` AND
     `rs`.`id` = `tgrs`.`insert_id`;

  DELETE
  FROM `temp_generate_rand_string`
  WHERE `first_inserted_in_this_run` = `_first_inserted_in_this_run`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39f6f/1)</kbd>

Comment: Ok, I was going crazy, started thinking you couldn't put select statement in WHILE. Any suggestions how to return the newly inserted rows from rand_strings, at the end of procedure?

Comment: I cannot do a ´SELECT * WHERE id >= _first_inserted_in_this_run` because of possible simultaneous INSERTs to rand_strings

Comment: One option may be using a temporary table. See updated answer.

Comment: I went with the temp table solution. Thanx!